# Custom build for spring-cloud-dataflow-server:2.5.0.RELEASE failing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to do a custom build of "spring-cloud-dataflow-server:2.5.0.RELEASE" to add my Oracle driver. But it's failing. I have used the dependencies used for 2.2.0

```
22-05-2020 16:35:52.724 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.configuration.metadata.ApplicationConfigurationMetadataResolverAutoConfiguration.metadataResolver
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:59) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at com.example.customdataflowserver.CustomDataflowServerApplication.main(CustomDataflowServerApplication.java:25) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:47) [custom-dataflow-server-maven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:86) [custom-dataflow-server-maven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [custom-dataflow-server-maven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [custom-dataflow-server-maven-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.hateoas.config.EntityLinksConfiguration] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@20ad9418]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:404) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:389) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:447) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:738) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:679) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:647) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1518) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:190) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:157) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:150) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:138) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:133) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:97) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:268) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:261) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:250) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:170) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:145) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:46) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/plugin/core/PluginRegistry
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        ... 47 common frames omitted
```

Below is my pom configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>custom-dataflow-server-maven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>custom-dataflow-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
        <spring-cloud-dataflow.version>2.5.0.RELEASE</spring-cloud-dataflow.version>
        <spring-security-oauth2.version>2.3.4.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth2.version>
        <mariadb.version>2.4.1</mariadb.version>
        <spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure.version>2.1.6.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure.version>
        <kubernetes-client.version>4.1.0</kubernetes-client.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dataflow-platform-cloudfoundry</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-oauth2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>kubernetes-client</artifactId>
            <version>${kubernetes-client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dataflow-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-dataflow.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
                <version>12.2.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>

            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

I tried adding Hateos dependency, which solved/suppressed the "EntityLinksConfiguration" error shown above and lead another error "[org.springframework.hateoas.config.WebFluxHateoasConfiguration]". But the same POM file is working for version "spring-cloud-dataflow.version: 2.2.0.RELEASE". I referred this link
[dataflow-server-22x](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/blob/master/custom-dataflow-builds/dataflow-server-22x/pom.xml) for building the custom version of 2.5.0.RELEASE.
What are all the dependencies I'm missing here? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added new working build files for [dataflow 2.5.x](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/master/custom-dataflow-builds/dataflow-server-25x)

Comment: Thanks Janne. The server is up and running. But failing to retrieve the task page in Dashsboard. Seems the Task_definition table has been updated with description column,  but I don't see it in "spring-cloud-task-core-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar". Can you please let me know where i could find the DDLs for SCDF.?

Comment: If you are completely working outside of automatic flyway schema handling, starting from dataflow 2.6.x, we now have ddl's at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/tree/master/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core/src/main/resources/schemas